# Exception when using POI FontFormatting setFontColor

Tags: java, apache-poi

Trying to use POI conditional formatting. I have the following method:

```
private final static Color PEAK_ORANGE = new Color(255, 239, 221);

public ConditionalFormattingRule getConditionalFormatting(ConditionalFormattingRule formattingContainer, FormatSpecs format){

    FontFormatting fontFmt = formattingContainer.createFontFormatting();
    fontFmt.setFontStyle(true, false);
    // fontFmt.setFontColorIndex((short)11);
    fontFmt.setFontColor(new XSSFColor(PEAK_ORANGE));

    PatternFormatting patternFmt = formattingContainer.createPatternFormatting();
    patternFmt.setFillBackgroundColor(new XSSFColor(PEAK_ORANGE));
    return formattingContainer;
}
```

When I use the `setFontColor()` method I get index out of bounds exception.

[image]

When I use the `setFontColorIndex()` method using some arbitrary index value, I do not get the exception. Notice however that I use the exact same color reference in the call to set the background color

> patternFmt.setFillBackgroundColor(new XSSFColor(PEAK_ORANGE));

and this works fine, no exceptions.

Has anyone else run into this? Am I missing something in the call to set the font color? I prefer to use my colors rather than those from the IndexedColors class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a small bug in Apache POI, a simple workaround is to first set an index-color and then set the actual intended full color, i.e.

```
    fontFmt.setFontColorIndex((short)1);
    fontFmt.setFontColor(new XSSFColor(PEAK_ORANGE));
```

The `setFontColorIndex()` will initialize the internal structures so that `setFontColor()` will work.

FYI, the bug should be fixed in time for release 4.0 of Apache POI.